# How can I display SMS poll results real time with Mobile Connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk

I'd like show real time results on screen in a web browser.

Before Mobile Connect everything was in the Email application and could be done with Data Extensions and AMP Script.

With Mobile Connect there is a disconnect with the Email application. Presumably this gap is filled by the FUEL SDK. However it does not appear that there is anything in the Mobile API to pull message results.

Any solutions out there for this?

Comment: To be honest - I haven't tried this with MC yet.  For reference, the Fuel SDK bridges the REST/SOAP gap, but if the functionality is missing - it's not filling that void.  I'll try it out and see if I can get you some real code.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. It was so easy before MC, and I'm sure there is a simple way still. Just not obvious. Could be a great HUB Exchange App as well.

Comment: Agreed. You should also be able to use AMPscript in a text message - have you attempted that?

Comment: Personalization strings and simple things like that. But I haven't tried to access any data extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kelly stated this can be done through AMP Script in the message. I set up a response campaign with the following in the response message:

```
%%[
SET @response = UPPERCASE([MSG(0).NOUN(0)])
UPSERTDATA("DE",1,"id",MOBILE_NUMBER,"response",@response)
]%%
Your vote for "%%=V(@response)=%%" has been recorded. Thank you!
```

"Text KEYWORD and your answer to SHORTCODE."

Then I use a landing page and a javscript to refresh a graph from the data extension.

Comment: Old school baby. Let's get them to add some REST routes for that and make us all a little happier :)

Comment: Yes it would be great to have some more power. But getting things into the data extension is an ok route.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only way to do this is the old fashioned way - create a basic text message in MobileConnect, and utilize AMP script to pass the data into a data extension.  You can retrieve data extension rows via REST API now, which might allow this to be a little easier. Let me know if you try a few things and get stuck - we can create a new question and address your concerns.

Comment: Mark that  as the answer, and give yourself the credit!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to this data as an sObject (forgive my ignorance here, but i've done next to nothing with exact target), you can utilize the streaming api to update your Visualforce page whenever a record is created/updated/deleted/undeleted. in realtime.

Comment: This is specifically for ExactTarget, and your answer doesn't apply here - thanks for trying though - it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion, try out the new MessageContact History API.  This shows the MT/MO traffic generated from a conversation:

```
Example Request

http://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/messageContact/MTA3ODo3ODow/history/MENqMHZHV2x3a0M1dG1iOHVnam9LZzo3OTow/mobileNumber/1120816001

Example Response

{
  "count": 5,
  "createDate": "2013-12-19T14:35:35.51",
  "status": "Active",
  "history": [
    {
      "type": "MT",
      "message": "Send your first name!",
      "date": "2013-12-19T14:35:35.51"
    },
    {
      "type": "MO",
      "message": "Anna",
      "date": "2013-12-19T14:36:36.04"
    },
    {
      "type": "MT",
      "message": "Text your ZIP code!",
      "date": "2013-12-19T14:36:36.6"
    },
    {
      "type": "MO",
      "message": "46202",
      "date": "2013-12-19T14:37:03.8"
    },
    {
      "type": "MT",
      "message": "Thanks!",
      "date": "2013-12-19T14:37:03.88"
    }
  ]
}
```

A similar API is available for conversations started with the QueueMO API.

https://code.exacttarget.com/api/queuemo-history

```
David Galante
MobileConnect, Product Manager
@davidgalante
```